# Jmeter-how to pass special characters in Parameters in both Name and Value

Tags: parameters, jmeter

I have to pass Parameters in Jmeter which has "," "$". These are all been taken with 2%24

Below is the Parameter and Value:

```
Parameter:Tabslan$ctl02$gvTasks2$ctl00$ctl06$rptrComments$ctl01$FC$hdnUserName
Value: at1+Tra+AN,+(Ph:+001-001-001)
```

But In the Post Data this is read as:

```
Parameter:Tabslan2%24ctl02%24gvTasks2%24ctl00%24ctl06%24rptrComments%24ctl01%24FC%24hdnUserName
Value: at1+Tra+AN%2C+LPN%2C+MD%2C+RN%2C+BS%2C+BA+%28Ph
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Given you record your test with [JMeter's built-in proxy server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) - you should get good HTTP Request sampler configuration which comes from recording
2. If you are building your request manually, it mostly depends on

   - "Encode?" checkbox state

     [image: JMeter HTTP Request Encode]
   - and what you are using to verify your request as it may appear differently in "Raw" and "HTTP" tabs of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

     [image: Post Data View Results Tree]

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for comprehensive information on the most common JMeter troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: Thanks so much . It helps!

Comment: I have a clarification. How do we specify content-type . I added content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  it throws me error. But if i use application/json;charset=utf-8 it works fine. But the actual post doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

If it Get request, disable the `encode` checkbox.

[image]

If it is Post request, keep the data in `Post Body` section in `key1=value1&key2=value2` format.

example Post Data:

```
Tabslan$ctl02$gvTasks2$ctl00$ctl06$rptrComments$ctl01$FC$hdnUserName=at1+Tra+AN,+(Ph:+001-001-001)&otherkey=othervalue
```

if more than one key-value pair, separate them by `&`
[image]